# Why a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $S$ such that $||x||>k$ cannot be a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

This is an excerpt from my text:

> A set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be compact if for all sequences of points $\{x_k\}$ such that $x_k\in S$ for each $k$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{m(k)}\}$ of $\{x_k\}$ and a point $x\in S$ such that $x_{m(k)}\rightarrow x$.
>
> If $S\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, it is easy to see that $S$ must be bounded. For, if $S$ were unbounded, it would be possible to pick a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $S$ such that $||x_k||>k$ and such a sequence cannot contain a convergent subsequence.

I can see that if I write down some a sequence that satisfies $||x_k||>k$ for $k=1,2,\dots$ then any subsequence of it would be non convergent. But I don't know how to show this formally. I think I need to show that:

There exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $k(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $k>k(\epsilon)$ such that $d(x_k,x)\ge \epsilon$, where $d$ is the distance function.

is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that convergent sequences need to be Cauchy.  However, we can prove that unbounded sequences cannot be Cauchy:

Consider any $n \in \Bbb N$.  Let $M = \|x_n\|$.  We may select a $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $k > M + 1$, which would mean that $\|x_k\| > k  > M$.  We then note that
$$
\|x_k - x_n\| \geq \|x_k\| - \|x_n\| > (M+1) - M = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\|x_k\| > k$ for all $k$ and $\{n_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers, then $\|x_{n_k}\| > n_k \ge k$ for all $k$ too. In particular every subsequence is unbounded. Unbounded sequences cannot converge.

Answer (score 1):

You should see that any convergent sequence, implies that it is bounded by definition.
If you take its contraposition, it tells that if a sequence is not bounded it is divergent. Hence, you have the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove, or use if you have seen it before, that convergent sequences are bounded.  Further hint for how to show this fact: consider the $\epsilon-N$ definition with $\epsilon = 1$.  What is the largest value that can be attained by the sequence $\{x_n\}$?